# Запись в csv, поиск по тэгу

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, urllib

```
#! usr/bin python3

import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()


f = open('text.txt', 'r')
l = [line.strip() for line in f]

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    search = soup.find('div', class_='search-total js-search-total')
    span = soup.find('span', class_='search-message js-page-title')
    spantext = span.text
    searchtext = search.text

    save (searchtext, spantext, 'project.csv')

def save(searchtext, spantext, path):
    with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(('Название', 'Кол-во'))
        for row in l:
            writer.writerow((spantext, searchtext))
        csvfile.close()


def main():
    for url in l:
        parse(get_html(url))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

В project.csv в итоге получается 2 строчки с одинаковыми данными, хотя 2 урла в text.txt разные , и данные в них , соответственно, тоже разные.

Куда посоветуете обратить внимание ?

p.s. может кто-нибудь знает, каким образом можно проверить наличие того или иного тега в html ?

Comment: старайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос, то есть: (1) первый вопрос: *"как проверить наличие того или иного тега в html* (используя beautifulsoup)?" (2) второй вопрос: проблема с записью в csv: опишите ожидаемый результат и что вместо этого получаете, привидите [*минимальный* полный пример кода, который показывает проблему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jfs Если я использую for row in l, то нужная мне информация в csv записывается дважды (из-за l в цикле)
Если я убираю цикл, то шапка (Название и Кол-во) пишется перед каждой строкой, которая парсится, обращаясь к text.txt

Comment: не помещайте необходимую для ответа информацию в комментарии, [обновите ваш вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/471394/edit) или разбейте на два вопроса как я предложил.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, поставьте напротив него галочку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    search = soup.find('div', class_='search-total js-search-total')
    span = soup.find('span', class_='search-message js-page-title')
    return span.text, search.text

def save(search, span, writer):
    writer.writerow(span, search)

def main():
    with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
        with open('project.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csf.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerow('Name', 'Amount')
            for line in f:
                span, search = parse(get_html(line.strip()))
                save(search, span, writer)
```

Кстати, раз уж вы так `pythonic` используете `with`, `close(csvfile)` совершенно лишний.

Comment: Да, благодарю, работает лучше !

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik, работает лучше - неверно, оно работает. В отличие от того, что было)))

Comment: работало и раньше, но с оговоренными выше косяками.